# Parsing csv data format in apache Camel

Tags: csv, apache-camel, camel-ftp, camel-sql, akka-camel

I followed an example from a book Camel in action. how to marshal and unmarshal csv data format. However, I want to unmarshal a csv file with (comma seperated delimiter) and split body. Then, I will use content based `.choice` to distribute messages according to required tasks. 
In fact, The first and simple example didn't work for me. I used camel 2.15.6 (camel-core, camel-context, camel-csv, commons-csv) and  java 7.

```
public void configure()
             {
              CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();
              csv.setDelimiter(",");

              from("file:test?noop=true")
             .unmarshal().csv()
              .split(body())
              .to("file:out");
             }
```

Please find below the stack trace.
[image]

Comment: the stacktrace doesn't indicate anything. When you say it didn't work for you. What is happening.

Comment: The program terminated without copying a file .to("file:out");

Comment: where is your file test? check if the path is correct.

Comment: The path is correct, because Camel locks the file (for example test\standard.csv.camelLock ), then, the program shut down. I no know why unmarshalling does not work.

Comment: try without split. I think split function requires a token to split which you are not specifying

Comment: not working too

Comment: Please show how you are running your application. I believe closed before Camel does anything. Here is some information about that: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: That is not a stack trace. And please paste as **text** and **not image**.

Comment: try .unmarshal(csv). Unmarshal takes reference to DataFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by removing noop=true? Actually, if noop is true, the file is not moved or deleted in any way. This option is good for readonly data, or for ETL type requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Pass csv as a parameter like this:

```
public void configure()throws Exception
         {
          CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();
          csv.setDelimiter(",");

          from("file:test?noop=true")
            .unmarshal(csv)
            .split(body())
            .to("file:out");
         }
```

Or it will help you to set contain based routing:I filter according to header of CSV:

```
//Route 1 for filter CSV based on header
        from("file:/home/r2/Desktop/csvFile?noop=true")
            .choice().when(body().contains("partyName"))
                .to("direct:partyNameCSV")
            .when(body().contains("\"stuffName\""))
                .to("direct:stuffNameCSV")
            .otherwise().endChoice();   

        //Route 2 partyNameCSV
        from("direct:partyNameCSV")
            .unmarshal(csv)
            .process(new PartyNameCSVProcessor())
            .end();

        //Route 3 stuffNameCSV
        from("direct:stuffNameCSV")
            .unmarshal(csv)
            .process(new StuffCSVProcessor())
            .end();
```